How can I get taskpane focused event, through outlook js Addin
I'm working with the outlook JS addin, want to perform some actions when the taskpane gets focused.
I checked for Office.EventType.TaskPaneSelectionChanged and itemChanged events but it didn't worked.
Can you help me with it
I'm using new outlook,
Microsoft Outlook Version 1.2024.424.300 (Production).
Client Version is 20240419007.18
